# How can I configure a SEN through the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, bitbucket-server

This question is about turning a pirated version into a legal one. If this violates any SO rules please let me know or delete it...

My very small company has been using Atlassian Stash 2.10.1 for several years. Apparently my predecessor somehow circumvented the license check, as I see a SEN (support entitlement number) consisting of only zeros.

I would like to purchase a cheap license for our small team of <10 developers which costs 10 USD, and then I would like to upgrade that old Stash version to the latest Bitbucket version.

I have tried out this process and it looks like the upgrade is successful, but then when I try loading the web interface I get long stacktraces, and at the bottom I find the cause:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.atlassian.nps.plugin.bitbucket.SupportEntitlementNumberDataProvider.getSEN(SupportEntitlementNumberDataProvider.java:35)
com.atlassian.nps.plugin.bitbucket.SupportEntitlementNumberDataProvider.get(SupportEntitlementNumberDataProvider.java:21)
com.atlassian.nps.plugin.bitbucket.SupportEntitlementNumberDataProvider.get(SupportEntitlementNumberDataProvider.java:9)
com.atlassian.plugin.webresource.impl.config.Config.getWebResourceData(Config.java:1092)
....
```

So I would like to know: Is there any way to add my SEN if I cannot use the web interface at all? Can I insert it into the DB directly or in some config file? I tried searching for some keywords but couldn't find anything.

I have not yet purchased the license since I would first like to confirm that I will be able to upgrade. But maybe I could also purchase it and then ask the Atlassian support; do you think they would be willing to help me?

Edit: This is running on an Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer this myself with my solution.

First I restored everything to Stash. I downloaded a clean stash and compared the code with our production version, which showed the changes that had been made to the license processing code. I undid those changes until I was able to enter a new license.

I got an evaluation license from Atlassian and used that on our Stash. After that I performed the upgrade procedure again, and this time it works fine afterwards. I then purchased the real license and entered that.